# Split function treating dashes oddly

Tags: google-sheets

Why does `=SPLIT("1,2-5,4", ",")`

equal

`1` `42040` `4`

instead of

`1`  `2-5` `4` ?

I have all of the cells formatted at plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement JPV's answer.

You can use:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*?),(.*?),(.*)")`

which is "hard-coded" to splitting exactly 3 elements (as JPV's is). To give more flexibility, you can use something like:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1&REPT(",",10),REPT("(.*?),",10))`

which is limited to a maximum of 10 elements (that number can be changed to suit). However, it will output an array that is always that maximum number of elements long (padded out with blank cells). You could use QUERY or FILTER to filter out those blank cells - the formula will become a little convoluted.

Alternatively, you can "code" your string such that automatic date coercion is avoided, and then "uncode" it after the SPLIT:

`=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","x"),","),"x","-"))`

Answer (score 5):

Regextract should give you the desired output. Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(regexextract("1,2-5,4", {"^(\d+),",",(.+),",",(\d+)$"}))
```

Comment: @pnuts: Seems like a good thing: no ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_thinking.. so... thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

With `1,2-5,4` in a cell this can be split as required with Data > Split text into columns... .